# C# Unit Test using FileStream

Tags: c#, unit-testing, filestream

I had a service that would return an image's data URLs, and I want to do unit test for it.

The following is part of its: ("path" parameter is a real path route)

```
...
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    if (bytesRead < buffer.Length)
    {
        return ...
    }   
    ...
    return ......
}
```

So my question is, how can I mock FileStream without a real path? I used xUnit and Substitute and found that FileStream can use Substitute but not know why it needs a real path for the parameter. How else can I try? Is there any way except to use wrapper?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can write to a temporary file and use that. Otherwise you have to mock the stream creation itself. It's easier if you use a `Stream` and not directly a `FileStream`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel In fact, my choice tends to be to mock the path or FileStream over using a wrapper rather than writing to a temporary file, so I will only consider writing to the temporary archive if the wrapper cannot be used. In addition, I wrote the service first and then did the unit testing, so when I looked up various unit test writing methods, I later realized that using Stream was more suitable. It was already too late...

Comment: [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Have thought about it but haven't considered it yet... It seems like perhaps using wrapper is the only better way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is generalizing the method parameter by accepting a `Stream` object. I assume your current method signature is something like

```
public byte[] GetImageData(string path)
```

Change your method to:

```
public byte[] GetImageData(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    // return your data.
}
```

In this way, you shift the responsibility of getting the `FileStream` to the clients and pass in a `FileStream` instead. Now you are in a more liberal situation when passing the parameter: In actual code you can pass in a real `FileStream`:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream("path/to/file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] data = parser.GetImageData(fileStream);
```

or you can freely create a `MemoryStream` according to your needs in your test code:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
// Manipulate your stream object as you like.
byte[] data = parser.GetImageData(stream);
```

This is actually an example of *programming to interfaces, not concrete implementations* and *dependency injection*. One bonus with this approach is that you will not incur the performance penalty of disk IO in your unit tests.

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't change the parameter passed in, so I finally decided to use a wrapper to solve it instead. Another question I have now is how to use wrapper to mock fileStream.Length...

Comment: Do you own the source code of the service? If so, why cannot you change the parameter? If you can use what I suggest then it is trivial to pass a `MemoryStream` for your test needs. You can control its content, length; whichever you want.

Comment: Yes, I have the source code, but for some reasons (if I change the parameters, the front-end also needs to be modified, the program can only make minor modifications when doing unit test, etc.) I cannot change the parameters. At that time, the program was written first and then tested. Therefore, many problems with the original writing method were only discovered during the test... In short, it was finally solved with wrapper.

Comment: If I encounter a reading and writing program next time, I will think again about how to test conveniently without affecting the program logic. This time I learned a lesson.

Comment: When you use the *test first* approach of TDD then you already design a testable code in the first place.

Comment: This is what I encountered... I didn't understand the practice of TDD well before writing unit tests. It wasn't until I sat through unit tests that I discovered that it could help me refactor better. ; (